# Is DataSource Pattern used with UITableView an example of dependency injection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Its not tightly coupled with the tableview, information about the tableview's configuration is injected via an implementation of UITableViewDataSource protocol.

Is this a good example of dependency injection in iOS development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be considered an example of dependency injection. A simple definition of dependency injection is:

> Dependency injection is a design pattern where an object's
>   dependencies and collaborators are set by an external entity, not by
>   themselves.

With the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol we actually separate the `UITableViewController` itself from the data source it needs to do its work. That means that the class that creates the `UITableViewController` can configure it with whatever data source it wants, improving its reusability and testability (two common goals of dependency injection).